# BLE, the more characteristics and services the more slowly

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy

**BLE and Android, the more characteristics and services the more slowly**

Following problem:

I’m working on a project with android (5.0+) and a `Nordic BLE chip (NRF52832)` to receive values from the chip on the android device.
(I don’t use third party packages)

Connect, readout the services and the characteristics works well and fast, but:

As soon as I set more characteristics (in 2 services) on notify, the values arrive the device very slow, for example:

> Notify 1 characteristic = 50ms/value
>
> Notify 1 service 6 characteristic = 150 – 200ms/value
>
> Notify 2 service, 10 characteristics = 400-600ms/value`

`RequestConnectionPriority` won’t solve my case.

Does anyone have a solution statement or already a solution?

Comment: The throughput can measured in notifications per second. It doesn't matter which characteristic. So if you notify the same characteristic twice that is the same as notifying two characteristics once.

Answer (score 0):

It is a know problem that using multiple services and characteristics can slow down the communication between a BLE center and a peripheral.

Furthermore, each characteristic has an overhead cost in terms of memory consumed on the device.

A solution to this problem is to minimize the number of characteristics you're using.

To do so, you could for instance use only one characteristic and dedicate one octet of the characteristic packet to storing the command id or info type you're sending or receiving from the device.

The same characteristic can then be used to send various command to your device, or to request various type of info from the device.

Comment: Thanks.
Means there is no “real” solution for the problem. Just minimize the number of the characteristics and use one service. The different values of the BLE center should be calculate, disassembly on the device!?

Comment: Yes indeed, minimizing the number of characteristics and use one service is a good approach. Your device will act differently depending on the value of the dedicated "command" byte of your characteristic.